# ORACLE SQL Group By financial year

Tags: sql, oracle

Count the number of people who joined the company per financial year. 1st April to 31st March.

```
select
case when month(joinDate)>=7 THEN concat(year(joindate),year(joindate)+1)
     else concat (year(joinDate)-1,year(joindate))
     end as Financial_Year
from employees
group by Financial_Year
```

Comment: Please provide more info and post an example / code or anything you have tried until now.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `year()` and `month()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ADD_MONTHS` and `EXTRACT` function to achieve the same.

```
SELECT
    FINANCIAL_YEAR || '-' || FINANCIAL_YEAR + 1 AS FINANCIAL_YEAR,
    NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES_JOINED
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(JOINDATE, - 3)) FINANCIAL_YEAR,
            COUNT(1) NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES_JOINED
        FROM
            EMPLOYEES
        GROUP BY
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(JOINDATE, - 3))
    );
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*),
case when month(joinDate)>=7 THEN concat(year(joindate),year(joindate)+1)
     else concat (year(joinDate)-1,year(joindate))
     end as Financial_Year
from employees
group by Financial_Year
```

Using the simple COUNT(*) aggregate function should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract (or add) 6 months and aggregate:

```
select add_months(join_date, -6) as fiscal_year,
       count(*)
from employees
group by add_months(join_date, -6)
order by min(join_date);
```

If you want the results as "2019-2020", then:

```
select extract(year from add_months(join_date, -6)) || '-' || extract(year from add_months(join_date, +6)) as fiscal_year,
       count(*)
from employees
group by extract(year from add_months(join_date, -6)) || '-' || extract(year from add_months(join_date, +6))
order by min(join_date);
```

If you are trying to do this in MySQL (which your syntax suggests):

```
select concat_ws('_',
                 year(join_date - interval 6 month),
                 year(join_date + interval 6 month
                ) as fiscal_year,
         count(*)
from employees
group by fiscal_year;
```